# Is the concatenation of all prime numbers, a universe/disjunctive number?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> A universe number is a number which contain any finite length string of digits for a base.

Reference [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nombre_univers). These are usually called "disjunctive numbers" in English.

Then the question is, is the concatenation of all prime numbers, a disjunctive number?

By the [Rosser Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_theorem) we can find that $$\forall n \ge 6,\text{ }\ln(n)+\ln\left(\ln(n)\right)-1<\frac{p_n}{n}<\ln(n)+\ln\left(\ln(n)\right)$$
where $p_n$ is the n-th number prime.

But I don't know what to do after. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Since your question is in English, could you provide an English reference for "universe number"? The phrase "for a basis" is not clear.

Comment: Sorry I am french so I can't. I added the translation request :-)

Comment: I think a "universe number" is like a [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) (the decimal expansion contains all finite-length strings), but without the restriction that the strings are distributed uniformly.

Comment: @Ryan: I think it's called a _disjunctive number_ in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using [bounds on prime gaps](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/gaps.html) it is possible to show that for any digit string not starting with $0$ there are an infinite number of primes whose decimal representation begins with that string.  It follows that the concatenation of all primes contains every finite digit string.

Furthermore, the real number whose digits correspond to the concatenation of all primes is known as the [Copeland–Erdős constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copeland%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_constant) and it is known to be normal in base $10$, so not only does this sequence contain every finite digit string, every string occurs with the same frequency we would expect if it were random.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

From [Istrate and Paun](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X9490037X) we have that, for a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers (such as, trivially, the primes) $a$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$, and for some base $b > 1$, we may concatenate the base-$b$ expansions of $a$ to produce a disjunctive sequence.

From the prime number theorem, we have $p \sim n \log n$. Therefore $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} = 1$, where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime.

Therefore, the sequence produced by concatenating prime integers contains all words, in any base $b > 1$.

See [Calude, Priese, and Staiger](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.34.1370) for a nice introduction to the subject.

Comment: Which theorem from (Discrete Appl. Math, pp83-86, 1994) are you illustrating?

Comment: @Shadock : Sorry; it's Theorem 1. I have updated the answer to include a link to the paper itself, as I should originally have done.